# Hypothesis testing with multiple restrictions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X_i$ are independent $N(\mu_i,1)$ random variables for $i = 1,..,n$. Consider the following test of $H_0: \mu_1 = ... = \mu_n = 0$ vs $H_1: \mu_i \neq 0$ for some $i < n$ with critical region $A_1 = \{(x_1, ..., x_n): \Sigma^n_{i=1} x_i > k_1\}$ such that the test has significant level $\alpha$.  Find $k_1$.

I don't know how to proceed with this question. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to find the distribution of $\sum_{I=1}^nX_i$ given $H_0$ is true? That's a good place to start. Once you do this you should be able to establish $k_1$ so that $\mathbb{P}(A_1|H_0)=\alpha$.

Comment: I know how to find the distribution of $\Sigma^n_i  X_i$ which is just $N(\Sigma \mu_i, n^{-1})$. But under $H_0$, the sum of means is just 0, which could be the case that the means cancel out rather than summing up to 0.